# How do I install Ruby 1.9.3 on Ubuntu without RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I want to install ruby 1.9.3 on Ubuntu without rvm

I run

```
sudo apt-get install ruby
```

It's taking ruby 1.8 and ruby 1.9.1.

And if I do

```
sudo apt-get install ruby 1.9.3 -p XXXX
```

I am still not able to install ruby. How can I install ruby on Ubuntu?

Comment: Download source code from ruby-lang.org, and compile yourself. I don't see why it is hard unless you don't have linux experience at all

Comment: I guess this is a valid way, but it also requires you to apply patches yourself and recompile from time to time. RVM alleviates a lot of that pain and I guess the OP wants to be able to just run apt-get upgrade to get the newest fixes for his ruby version.

Comment: It seems worth asking *why* you want to avoid RVM. I find it's easy to unnecessarily limit ourselves because we've misunderstood something, and you can generally get the best help if you explain your actual goal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1st approach

Source
         http://lenni.info/blog/2012/05/installing-ruby-1-9-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pengolin/

The new Ubuntu release has just rolled around and with it a slew of new packages. Personally, I'm tracking the development of Ruby quite closely but the default Ruby on Ubuntu ist still the 1.8 series which I can't recommend. Ruby 1.9 has some performance improvements and 1.9.3 in particular a lot of them compared to 1.9.2.

However, as I have elaborated in a previous post getting the Ruby 1.9 series on Ubuntu without using RVM instead of 1.8 isn't all that easy. Please read the post if you are interested in the details.

The short version is: You can get Ruby 1.9.3-p0 by installing the ruby-1.9.1 package. (The package is called 1.9.1 because that is the ABI version.)

If you want to make Ruby 1.9 the default do the following:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1 ruby1.9.1-dev \

 rubygems1.9.1 irb1.9.1 ri1.9.1 rdoc1.9.1 \ build-essential libopenssl-ruby1.9.1 libssl-dev zlib1g-dev

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ruby ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 400 \
     --slave   /usr/share/man/man1/ruby.1.gz ruby.1.gz \
                /usr/share/man/man1/ruby1.9.1.1.gz \
     --slave   /usr/bin/ri ri /usr/bin/ri1.9.1 \
    --slave   /usr/bin/irb irb /usr/bin/irb1.9.1 \
    --slave   /usr/bin/rdoc rdoc /usr/bin/rdoc1.9.1

# choose your interpreter
# changes symlinks for /usr/bin/ruby , /usr/bin/gem
# /usr/bin/irb, /usr/bin/ri and man (1) ruby


 sudo update-alternatives --config ruby
 sudo update-alternatives --config gem

# now try
 ruby --version
```

If you want to make this your exclusive Ruby and get rid of Ruby 1.8 follow the uninstallation instructions.

Edit: I found out today that there also is a package called ruby1.9.3 however that is just a proxy package that doesn't have any files itself and only depends on ruby1.9.1. Aptitude confirms this:

Ruby uses two parallel versioning schemes: the `Ruby library compatibility version' (1.9.1 for this package), which is similar to a library SONAME, and the 'Ruby version' (1.9.3 for this package). Ruby packages in Debian are named using the Ruby library compatibility version, which is sometimes confusing for users who do not follow Ruby development closely. This package depends on the ruby1.9.1 package, and provides compatibility symbolic links from 1.9.3 executables and manual pages to their 1.9.1 counterparts.

There doesn't seem to be a rubygems1.9.3.

2nd approach

Also This link i found useful its very simple and effective.

http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

Answer (score 25):

On Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I got it to work with the following:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby 1.9.3
cd /etc/alternatives
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/ruby1.9.3 ruby
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me and is by far the easiest way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: E: Couldn't find any package by regex '1.9.3' ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 8):

Use the brightbox packages for 1.9.3. You will have to add their repo though but to keep it short here just use their help pages: http://blog.brightbox.co.uk/posts/next-generation-ruby-packages-for-ubuntu

Answer (score 4):

**Compiling from Source** is the standard way.

Download source code from [Here](http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p194.tar.gz), Use README file to get instruction.

Another method is apt package manager system.

```
$ sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1
```

Yes, this will install Ruby 1.9.2. It has a ‘library compatibility version’ of 1.9.1, hence the name.

If you install the ‘ruby’ package, you’ll get the older Ruby 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

In my cluster this is really the only solution that worked:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# -- this really is the only solution that worked for me on snap :/

ruby -v
if ! command -v ruby &> /dev/null
then
    echo "Going to try to install ruby (ideally 3.1.2)"
    # - install rebenv (following ruby-build really is needed eventhough it doesn't look like it)
    mkdir -p ~/.rbenv
    cd ~/.rbenv
    git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git .
    # if $HOME/.rbenv/bin not in path append it, otherwise don't change it
    echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | awk '{print "  " $0}';
    if [[ ":$PATH:" != *":$HOME/.rbenv/bin:"* ]]; then
      echo "might want to put $HOME/.rbenv/bin in your path"
      export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
#      echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc.lfs
    fi
    eval "$(rbenv init -)"
    rbenv -v

    # - install ruby-build, odd, this really is needed for ruby to install despite it not looking like ruby build is need at the bottom
    mkdir -p ~/.ruby-build
    cd ~/.ruby-build
    git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git .
    # if $HOME/.ruby-build/bin not in path append it, otherwise don't change it
    echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | awk '{print "  " $0}';
    if [[ $PATH != *"$HOME/.ruby-build/bin"* ]]; then
      echo "might want to put $HOME/.ruby-build/bin in your path"
      export PATH="$HOME/.ruby-build/bin:$PATH"
#      echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc.lfs
    fi
    ruby-build --version

    # - install ruby without sudo -- using rbenv
    mkdir -p ~/.local
    #    ruby-build 3.1.2 ~/.local/
    rbenv install 3.1.2
    rbenv global 3.1.2
fi
ruby -v

# - Original Prover doesn't work on SNAP
# Proverbot's way to install ruby
#    # First, install Ruby, as that is for some reason required to build the "system" project
#    git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/ruby-build
#    mkdir -p ~/.local
#    PREFIX=~/.local ./ruby-build/install.sh
#    ~/.local/ruby-build 3.1.2 ~/.local/
# ref: https://superuser.com/questions/340490/how-to-install-and-use-different-versions-of-ruby/1756372#1756372
```