# RVM : Can't install Ruby 1.9.3-p551 (macOS)

Tags: ruby, installation, rubygems, rvm

My rvm version is 1.29.12 and macOS 11.2.3, here is the error messages.

```
Error running 'env GEM_HOME=/Users/yuanyuanliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global GEM_PATH= /Users/yuanyuanliu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby -d /Users/yuanyuanliu/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.7.9/setup.rb --no-document',
please read /Users/yuanyuanliu/.rvm/log/1618286479_ruby-1.9.3-p551/rubygems.install.log
```

then cat rubygems.install.log

```
Exception `LoadError' at /Users/yuanyuanliu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1264 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/operating_system
Exception `LoadError' at /Users/yuanyuanliu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1273 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/ruby
/Users/yuanyuanliu/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.9/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': /Users/yuanyuanliu/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.9/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_warn.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL (SyntaxError)
    module_function define_method(:warn) {|*messages, uplevel: nil|
                                                              ^
/Users/yuanyuanliu/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.9/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_warn.rb:18: void value expression
/Users/yuanyuanliu/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.9/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_warn.rb:43: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
    from /Users/yuanyuanliu/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.9/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/yuanyuanliu/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.9/lib/rubygems.rb:1390:in `<top (required)>'
    from setup.rb:28:in `require'
    from setup.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

```
'command gem pristine  --version ' failed, you need to fix these gems manually.
Error running '__rvm_with ruby-1.9.3-p551 gemset_pristine',
please read /Users/yuanyuanliu/.rvm/log/1618301825_ruby-1.9.3-p551/gemset.pristine-ruby-1.9.3-p551.log
Making gemset ruby-1.9.3-p551@global pristine - please wait

'command gem pristine  --version ' failed, you need to fix these gems manually.
Error running '__rvm_with ruby-1.9.3-p551@global gemset_pristine',
please read /Users/yuanyuanliu/.rvm/log/1618301825_ruby-1.9.3-p551/gemset.pristine-ruby-1.9.3-p551@global.log
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add to the question the commands you ran. Also note that Ruby 1.9 is beyond end-of-life, and no longer receives important updates. For instance, attempting to install Ruby 1.9 with RVM requires the deprecated libssl1.0-dev, which can put you at risk for severe security problems.

Comment: I'm pretty sure RubyGems 3.0.9 (released December, 20th 2020) does not support Ruby 1.9.3-p551 (released November, 11th 2014).

Answer (score 1):

`@Sam:` a lot of users, like myself, are still running production systems on `Ruby 1.9.3-p551` even though everyone screams EOL. Ignore them becuase the last I checked, my government (apparently most powerful in the world) is still running on 60 year old COBOL...LOL! Hey, if it's still making you money, why not?

Anyhow, I personally prefer using `rbenv` to manage my versions of Rubies. So, if you're able to use `rbenv`, you can follow my instructions below to get up and running with both `rbenv` and `ruby-1.9.3-p551` securely patched with `SSLv1, SSLv2, SSLv3 & TLSv1.2`:

```sh
# 1. Update brew and install OpenSSL/rbenv
brew update
brew install openssl
brew install rbenv

# 2. Set up rbenv in your shell
rbenv init

# 3. Close your Terminal window and open a new one so your changes take effect
# 4. Verify that rbenv is properly set up using this rbenv-doctor script
curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/master/bin/rbenv-doctor | bash

#  You should get a response with the following 2 last lines:
#  ----------------------------------------------------------
#> Checking RubyGems settings: OK
#> Auditing installed plugins: OK

# 5. Now, time to install Ruby 1.9.3-p551 w/ TLSv1_2 patch
# -- This process takes approx. 3-6mins on a Ubuntu 18.04 VPS
# -- Reference: https://niv.su/arch/ruby/2019/04/01/ruby1.9-openssl.html
rbenv install --force --patch 1.9.3-p551 < <(curl -sSL https://git.io/JOcZw)
# 6. Set, rbenv global and run rbenv rehash (optional)
rbenv global 1.9.3-p551
echo 'gem: --no-document' >> ~/.gemrc
rbenv rehash

# 7. Install Bunder version 1.17.3 as that is the only most recent supported 
# -- version with Ruby 1.9.3-p551
gem install bundler -v 1.17.3 --no-rdoc --no-ri
rbenv rehash

# 8. Locate your `bundle` executable and add require 'openssl' right below
# -- require 'rubygems' in that file
gem env | grep "EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY"
#> - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/robby/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/bin
nano /home/robby/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/bin/bundle
# -- save, exit and run:
rbenv rehash
ruby -v
#> ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407) [x86_64-linux]

# 9. At this point you should be all set and can run the following 
# -- command to ensure Ruby 1.9.3-p551 is successfully installed with the patch
curl -Lks 'https://git.io/rg-ssl' | ruby

# Your output should be similar to this except location directories for your SSL files
# -----------------------------------------------------------------
# Here's your Ruby and OpenSSL environment:
# 
# Ruby:           1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407) [x86_64-linux]
# RubyGems:       1.8.23.2
# Bundler:        1.17.3
# Compiled with:  OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
# SSL_CERT_FILE:  /usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem
# SSL_CERT_DIR:   /usr/lib/ssl/certs
# 
# With that out of the way, let's see if you can connect to rubygems.org...
# 
# Bundler connection to rubygems.org:       success ✅
# RubyGems connection to rubygems.org:      success ✅
# Ruby net/http connection to rubygems.org: success ✅
# 
# Hooray! This Ruby can connect to rubygems.org. You are all set to use Bundler and RubyGems.
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
I uppdated to ruby 2.2.5 last week lol.

Comment: Nice! Are you running a legacy app which requires a lower version of Ruby?

Comment: I hope I didn't come across as one of the "screamers," as I understand how some institutions continue using EOL software, and only want to pointed out some of the risks (which become apparent in an attempt install using RVM). I would suggest also adding your explanation here to questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078166/how-do-i-install-ruby-1-9-3-on-ubuntu-without-rvm) or even creating a new canonical self-answer question like "How can I install Ruby 1.9.3 even though it's EOL"