# Why would only using rbenv and ruby-build work to install ruby on ubuntu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried all the normal ways to install ruby: https://superuser.com/questions/340490/how-to-install-and-use-different-versions-of-ruby/1756372#1756372 in my cluster where I don't have admin permission (but they told me to install it locally myself).

The only solution that worked was:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# -- this really is the only solution that worked for me on snap :/

ruby -v
if ! command -v ruby &> /dev/null
then
    echo "Going to try to install ruby (ideally 3.1.2)"
    # - install rbenv (following ruby-build really is needed eventhough it doesn't look like it)
    mkdir -p ~/.rbenv
    cd ~/.rbenv
    git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git .
    # if $HOME/.rbenv/bin not in path append it, otherwise don't change it
    echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | awk '{print "  " $0}';
    if [[ ":$PATH:" != *":$HOME/.rbenv/bin:"* ]]; then
      echo "might want to put $HOME/.rbenv/bin in your path"
      export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
#      echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc.lfs
    fi
    eval "$(rbenv init -)"
    rbenv -v

    # - install ruby-build, odd, this really is needed for ruby to install despite it not looking like ruby build is need at the bottom
    mkdir -p ~/.ruby-build
    cd ~/.ruby-build
    git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git .
    # if $HOME/.ruby-build/bin not in path append it, otherwise don't change it
    echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | awk '{print "  " $0}';
    if [[ $PATH != *"$HOME/.ruby-build/bin"* ]]; then
      echo "might want to put $HOME/.ruby-build/bin in your path"
      export PATH="$HOME/.ruby-build/bin:$PATH"
#      echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc.lfs
    fi
    ruby-build --version

    # - install ruby without sudo -- using rbenv
    mkdir -p ~/.local
    #    ruby-build 3.1.2 ~/.local/
    rbenv install 3.1.2
    rbenv global 3.1.2
fi
ruby -v

# - Original Prover doesn't work on SNAP
# Proverbot's way to install ruby
#    # First, install Ruby, as that is for some reason required to build the "system" project
#    git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/ruby-build
#    mkdir -p ~/.local
#    PREFIX=~/.local ./ruby-build/install.sh
#    ~/.local/ruby-build 3.1.2 ~/.local/
# ref: https://superuser.com/questions/340490/how-to-install-and-use-different-versions-of-ruby/1756372#1756372
```

why? Is there something simpler or more official? (I do need 3.1.2)

---

related:

- [How do I install Ruby 1.9.3 on Ubuntu without RVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078166/how-do-i-install-ruby-1-9-3-on-ubuntu-without-rvm/75330109#75330109)
- [Unable to install Ruby on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68208645/unable-to-install-ruby-on-ubuntu/75330123#75330123)

Comment: In principle, using rbenv is the right approach. There are alternatives, but whether they're simpler... YMMV :) The best-known alternative is probably RVM, I'm personally a big fan of asdf-vm.

Answer (score 1):

The script looks fine to me, as you've no admin rights, the only choice that you have is to install it in the home of the user that needs it, and `rbenv` is the right tool to handle that.

The script is just aggregating all the required commands to install everything you need:

- `rbenv` (ruby environments manager) => https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#basic-git-checkout
- `ruby-build` (ruby versions manager) => https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build#clone-as-rbenv-plugin-using-git
- `ruby 3.1.2` (ruby version that you want) => https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installing-ruby-versions